# Duplicate meshes sharing materials when not intended

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine

**Blender 2.9, Eevee**

Edit: Somewhat solved now; the birds seem to share the uv unwrap and disconnecting one texture from uv fixed it.

I am having a problem where when I copy paste two of the same model, from two separate files, with two separate textures, the particles of the first pasted model take on the texture of the second model. The models are rigged with copies of the same armature.

To make it clearer, I made a new file(file1), to where I copy pasted a bird from another file(file2). When rendered in eevee, the bird looks normal. [image: Image of the bird one]

Then, when I paste another bird which uses same base model with different texture from another file (file3), the particle system colour of the first bird changes to that of the second bird's.[image: Picture with two birds, first one with wrong texture]

The texture of the bird itself stays correct. I have tried creating entirely new material and copying the old material's nodes onto it. Does not work.

In Cycles everything works normally.

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W1l0gLXzfRRHKq3FsSQPQCRo4i5kmbVD/view?usp=sharing)